# jQuery select previous element (sibling, not child)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to select and add a class the previous `h1` element to `.show_more`. I have tried using `prev()` and `closest()` but neither seem to be working, any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show_more').closest('h1').addClass('gummybear');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
<div class="show_more">Show More</div>
```

Comment: You can use element.parent().find() to solve this problem if it is on the same level as shown in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`closest()` searches for parents, so isn't applicable. `prev()` by itself won't work, as the `p` is between `.show_more` and the `h1`.

Instead you could use `prevAll('h1').first()`, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show_more').prevAll('h1').first().addClass('gummybear');
});
```

```css
.gummybear { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
<div class="show_more">Show More</div>
```

The `first()` can be omitted if you don't mind affecting all sibling `h1` elements, or if there only ever will be one of them (as there technically should be for SEO reasons).